# mutiple upload with rails and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, multi-upload

I am following this tutorial [here](http://www.railscook.com/recipes/multiple-files-upload-with-nested-resource-using-paperclip-in-rails/) to use multiple uploads with paperclip. 
However when I add the files I get the flash notice confirming the gallery was added succesfully but there are no images uploaded. I am sure its the implementation in my controller.

gallery_controller.rb

```
  def update
    @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
    if @gallery.save

      if params[:exhibition_images_attributes]
        params[:exhibition_images_attributes].each { |image|
          @gallery.exhibition_images.create(image: image)
        }
      end
        format.html { redirect_to @gallery, notice: 'Gallery was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @gallery }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @gallery.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @gallery = Gallery.friendly.find params[:id]
    @image = @gallery.exhibition_images.new

  end

private 

    def gallery_params
      params.require(:gallery).permit(:title, exhibition_images_attributes: [:image])
    end
```

upload form

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@gallery, :html => {:multipart => true}, layout: :horizontal, label_col: "col-sm-2", control_col: "col-sm-10") do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>    

<%= f.fields_for :exhibition_images do |f| %>
      <%= f.file_field "image[]", type: :file, multiple: true %>

    <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Create/Update", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

gallery.rb

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
    belongs_to :guide
  has_many :exhibition_images, :autosave => true
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exhibition_images 


end
```

exhibition_image.rb

```
class ExhibitionImage < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :gallery, :autosave => true

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "100x100", guide: "500x500" }
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

end
```

Comment: can you include your `params` that hit the `update` action in the question

Comment: I meant `params` from your logs